# Activiti: How to create a custom event and listen to it?

Tags: activiti

I am working on an activiti based java application.

As per my process definition, when task is created or assigned or completed, activiti engine invokes a custom task listener(extending TaskLIstener). This task listener performs some logging actions in elasticsearch.

I have a usecase which needs a different handling. I have exposed a rest API which a user can invoke to change priority of a task.

What I want is that when this API is invoked, my custom task listener,mentioned above, is also invoked. 
I am not sure how to achieve it. I guess I first need to create a custom event which is created when API is called(events offered by activiti won't help). And then, I somwhow need to link that custom event and my custom task listener.

Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: Hi, if no response is given here, you can use their forums, it used to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The userguide provides proper steps to define and call a custom event in your process definition in the [Event Handlers](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eventDispatcher) Section.

if you just want to set priority of a task then you should probably use [taskService.setPriority(...)](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/taskservice#setPriority-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: I am doing taskService.setPriority().But it doesn't invoke custom listener. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: you can dispatch the event using event Dispatcher https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eventDispatcherCustomEvents, you can set the priority and call the event after that

Comment: Thanks for input. So in the listener I can then get hold of task?

Comment: yes, make sure the event listener your define has entityType as `task`

Comment: I created listener extending BaseEntityEventListener, and instantiate it just before my call to setTskPriority(), and call ruTimeService.addEventListener() passing listener instanc. But I need to set entityType on listener, but can't see any such method on it.